# What's the difference between these 2 ways of calling express.router?

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I'm new to Node/Express, and while reading docs and doing some tutorials, I've found that the Express Router is initialized in 2 different ways. Is there any meaningful change between them?

Method 1:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
res.json({'Title': 'HELLO!'});
});

module.exports = router;
```

Method 2:

```
const { Router } = require('express');
const router = Router ();

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
res.json({'Title': 'HELLO!'});
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method 1:
It requires the express module and then calling the Router() function.

Method 2:
This functionality is called Object destructuring in Javascript. We're basically splitting that Particular function(Router) from the express object.

Refer [this](https://javascript.info/destructuring-assignment#object-destructuring) for more information.

Comment: Thanks. Does this have an impact on any kind of performance/speed? Considering in the first case I'm calling the whole object and on the second case I'm only importing one module

Comment: Theoretically, it should improve the performance as you're taking only what you need from the object. But this certainly improves the readability and makes the code clean and declarative.

Answer (score 1):

Method 1: The code first imports the Express application object, uses it to get a Router object.

Method 2: Here ES6 **object destruction** is used to import multiple child modules(or single in this instance) from one single module.

Method 2 is when you need to import multiple child modules from a single module with a single line of code. Else you'll have to include the whole object or import each child module separately.